# Find the closest word to set of words

Tags: python, nlp, word2vec, gensim

I would need to find something like the opposite of `model.most_similar()`
While `most_similar()` returns an array of words most similar to the one given as input, I need to find a sort of "center" of a list of words.

Is there a function in gensim or any other tool that could help me?

Example:
Given `{'chimichanga', 'taco', 'burrito'}` the center would be maybe `mexico` or `food`, depending on the corpus that the model was trained on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you supply a list of words as the `positive` argument to `most_similar()`, it will report words closest to their mean (which would seem to be one reasonable interpretation of the words' 'center').

For example:

```
sims = model.most_similar(positive=['chimichanga', 'taco', 'burrito'])
```

(I somewhat doubt the top result `sims[0]` here will be either 'mexico' or 'food'; it's most likely to be another mexican-food word. There isn't necessarily a "more generic"/hypernym relation to be found either between word2vec words, or in certain directions... but some other embedding techniques, such as [hyperbolic embeddings](https://dawn.cs.stanford.edu/2018/03/19/hyperbolics/), might provide that.)